# Laravel Eloquent Model with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have implemented eloquent relationship in my code but Laravel unable to read the function that I created to map the eloquent relationship in the model.

User Model

```
public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'userid');
    }
```

Product Model

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Product Controller

```
 $products = Product::with('Users')->Users()->where('users.isActive',1)->get();
        return view('product',compact('products'));
```

I keep getting error from the product controller, I also attached the error that I current encountered as below.
[image]

How can I get all the product and user data with the where condition such as "Users.isActive = 1".

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `whereHas` to filter from a relationship.

```
$products = Product::with('users')
    ->whereHas('users', function ($query) {
        $query->where('isActive', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

Also it is generally a good idea to use singular noun for `belongsTo` relationship because it returns an object, not a collection.

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

$products = Product::with('user')
    ->whereHas('user', function ($query) {
        $query->where('isActive', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

EDIT

If you want to retrieve users with products you should query with User model.

```
$users = User::with('products')
    ->where('isActive', 1)
    ->get();
```

Then you can retrieve both users and products by

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->products;
    // or
    foreach($users->products as $product) {
        $product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually my expected output is below https://ibb.co/5W2J5CJ

Comment: I have tested your provided solution but it will only return me the product dataset instead of the dataset of product and users.

I have tested to add the specific column selection in the ->get('users.*') but it has not work to display the users data.

Comment: @MiracleHades you may want to query with User model, see the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `whereHas()` method for this purpose. [Here is the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
$products = Product::with('users')->whereHas('users', function (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) {
    $query->where('isActive', 1);
})->get();

$users = $products->pluck('users');

return view('product',compact('products'));
```

Comment: Actually my expected output is below ibb.co/5W2J5CJ

Comment: I have tested your provided solution but it will only return me the product dataset instead of the dataset of product and users. I have tested to add the specific column selection in the ->get('users.*') but it has not work to display the users data.

Comment: @MiracleHades You should get `users` by `$products->pluck('users')` as it is a laravel collection

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo after the `with`, is `users` instead of `Users` and you're redundant about the Query Builder, remove the `->Users()`:

Before:

```
$products = Product::with('Users')->Users()->where('users.isActive',1)->get();
        return view('product',compact('products'));
```

After:

```
$products = Product::with('users')->where('users.isActive',1)->get();
            return view('product',compact('products'));
```

Fix that and all should work.

Comment: but I cant print the data from users table.

Comment: Try the Anurat's answer, that is a better way.

Comment: same got error, screenshoot: https://ibb.co/b6zdqrd

Comment: but the generated query is wrong, it should be
SELECT products.*,users.* FROM products INNER JOIN users ON products.userid = users.id WHERE users.email = 'oops@example.com';